How to change .contextMenu background?
I need to create element with contextMenu:

i am trying to change the background of contextMenu items, but they still remain ugly gray:

Could you please help me to manage this problem.
This is my code:
import SwiftUI

struct CoverButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
            .fill(Color.white.opacity(0.1))
            .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
            .overlay {
                Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
            }
            .contextMenu(menuItems: {
                Button("Add...", systemImage: "bookmark") {

                }
                Divider()
                Button("Remove", systemImage: "trash", role: .destructive, action: {

                } )
            })
    }
}

#Preview {
    CoverButton()
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
}

contextMenu items remain independent for colorScheme or background modificators...

It works for me using an iPhone 16 simulator with iOS 18.0. Maybe it's just an issue in Preview? Or are you on an older version of iOS?

To the point! It's canvas bug... Thank you!
